# How to use two different features in category.xml with profiles in Tycho Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

Currently, I have two projects with different `category.xml` files. Both `category.xml` files declare a separate feature:

`project1/category.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/myfeature.feature_1.6.0.qualifier.jar" id="myfeature.feature" version="1.6.0.qualifier">
      <category name="mycategory"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="mycategory" label="Category"/>
</site>
```

`project2/category.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/myfeature.advanced.feature_1.6.0.qualifier.jar" id="myfeature.advanced.feature" version="1.6.0.qualifier">
      <category name="mycategory"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="mycategory" label="Category"/>
</site>
```

Now, I want to merge `project1` and `project2` in a single project. Is it possible that I declare both features with two separate profiles? Then, I could run my maven build with `maven -P profile1 <goal>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category.xml file can refer to many different features - in fact, p2 repositories only include what is mentioned in the category.xml files.

So, depending on what you want to achieve, you could (a) have a single category.xml file in your repository project that refers to both features, or (b) have two repository projects, and merge them, e.g. declaring a [composite update site](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)) or (c) merging them using the [tycho p2 mirror tool](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Additional_Tools#mirror_goal).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I want to have one `category.xml` file which includes both features. However, on Maven build I want that only one gets selected, because if I run my Maven build with my first profile now, some dependencies are missing since both features in `category.xml` will be checked.

Comment: Indeed, that is not possible for exactly the reason you said. What you can do is create both repositories and merge them afterwards.